# Editing perl scripts on one server, but executing on another

Tags: linux, perl, ide

I have a Perl script which is currently located in my home directory on a Linux machine called server1. This server does not have a GUI, and I have to use vi/vim to edit files.

I am interested in using an IDE such as Padre or Eclipse instead since I have a hard time with vi/vim.

I have linux virtual machine(server2) which has a GUI and IDE installed.

Is it possible for me to map my home directory from server1 to server2 even if my home directory is password protected?

If so, when I edit the Perl script from the IDE on server2, will it execute my script on server1?

Basically, I am looking for a way to edit and launch scripts on one server(server 2),
but execute them on another(server1).

Answer (score 3):

Look up `mount` command. You can set it up to be able to read the remote directory on your development machine. See [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_file_system) or [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Ed has already mentioned [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) so you can mount a remote filesystem.

However, consider why you think you need to edit the file remotely. Why not do the development locally and deploy when it's ready? A good development process should support that. I tend to work locally, commit to whatever version control I'm using, and when I'm ready to test remotely I checkout the latest sources. I can do whatever I like on my local machine.

Comment: Excellent suggestion as it moves you towards separate dev/test and production environments.  Editing and testing on your VM then having an automated process to move the current version to your production machine is a big step towards better development.